# How to create webpack config in direflow to support optional chaining?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, compiler-errors, storybook

I am developing a react library using direflow. I am using one private node_modules package in my react component. This package contains modern javascript features like optional chaining and null coalescing.
Due to this whenever I try to build the library getting this error

> Unexpected token
> You may need appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loader s are configured to process this file at

```js
if(temp == action?.value){
       // some code
}
```

My webpack config:

```js
const {webpackConfig} = require("direflow-scripts"); 

 module.export = (config, env) => {
    ...webpackConfig(config, env)
}
```

I tried various options from official documentation of webpack but nothing worked.

Comment: Please share your webpack configuration

Comment: const {webpackConfig} = require("direflow-scripts"); module.export = (config, env) => { ...webpackConfig(config, env) }  This is in direflow-webpack.js